# pika: TypeError: queue_declare() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

According to [the doc](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.queue_declare), a callback argument should be supported. Also according to the source code.

I am doing

```
    def declare_ok(method: pika.frame.Method):
        while True:  # TODO busy waiting until a better way is found
            try:
                print(f"Attempting to bind {queue_name}")
                channel.queue_bind(queue=queue_name, exchange=queue_params.exchange,
                                   routing_key=queue_params.routing_key)
                print(f"Successful bind to {queue_name}")
                break
            except pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker as ex:
                time.sleep(0.1)
            except pika.exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError as ex:
                time.sleep(0.1)

    channel.queue_declare(queue_name, callback=declare_ok)
```

and getting

```
TypeError: queue_declare() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'
```

What's the correct way to pass a callback?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your channel is a `Channel`? There are other classes in that package which have a `queue_declare` method but, do not have a `callback` argument. If you created that channel based on some return value, I would definitely check it's type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of `pika` (v 1.3.2), the `BlockingChannel.queue_declare()` function signature has been changed to remove the `callback` parameter. See docs here: https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/f4d8f8ff02a4da4653749c86161b7d52e53f73fe/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py#L2483